# Critical section - single unit of execution or not?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, pthreads, critical-section

I know that a critical section is that part of a code which can't be accessed by multiple consumers (threads or processes) at a certain moment of time. Now here I am confused. Say, a critical section is expected to be executed by the CPU in 5 millisecond. 
So

- **Possibility 1:** will the CPU execute the critical section as a single unit of work and take 5 ms of time without scheduling other thread / consumers at that moment?
- **Possibility 2:** Or the consumer can be rescheduled after being executed for a time-slice like things happen in time sharing systems?

Comment: Threads can get scheduled out when they're executing within a critical section, so #2.

Comment: For possibility 1:Every process may not want critical section and since allocation of critical section is handled by various synchronizing mechanisms, we can have several processes under execution...